# Python string.split more than one value in for loop

Tags: python, string, split

Basically this works fine:

```
>>> x,y = "x=y".split("=")
>>> print x
x
```

But this gives an error:

```
>>> for x, y in "x=y".split("="):
...     print x
...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I am wondering what the difference is, and how I could fix this for loop.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Split on "=" gives you two values:

```
"x", "y"
```

The fact that those values match your variable names is incidental. You could also do:

```
x,xx = "x=y".split("=")
```

I suspect what you are likely planning is to take a list:

```
"foo=bar,blah=boo,etc=something"
```

And split it, for which you could do:

```
for x,y in [ (pair.split("=")) for pair in "foo=bar,blah=boo,etc=something".split(",") ]:
    print x,y
```

BUT! While it works, I think it would be much better to split it into individual steps as it's much more readable:

```
params = "foo=bar,blah=boo,etc=something"
pair_list = params.split(",")
for pair in pair_list:
    x,y = pair.split("=")
    ...
```

Comment: Yep, this is exactly what I intended to do, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Not cramming the list comprehension into the loop header is a good idea. Moving the tuple unpacking into the loop and introducing a bogus variable `pair` is not - just use `for x, y in pair_list` (ideally, `x` and `y` would get more meaningful names as well...).

Comment: @delnan, pair_list looks like ["foo=bar", "blah=boo", "etc=something"], it's not a list of tuples, but a list of strings. There are probably faster ways to process the whole string, but I think it would be a premature optimization. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, I somehow thought the pairs were already split (well, I would have suggested `pair_list = [raw_pair.split('=') for raw_pair in params.split(',')]`).

Comment: @delnan, no problem. BTW, that's effectively the first example I gave, but without assignment to a variable.

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```
for x in "x=y".split("="):
    # ...
```

What you tried is to iterate over the sequence `["x", "y"]`, but assign to `x, y` for each entry of the sequence.  That would be equivalent to

```
 x, y = "x"
```

for the first iteration, which does not make any sense.

Comment: Humm.. but I want to assign to "x".  Any way to do this without the extra step of saying, x = x[0] inside the for loop?

Comment: @user: Using `for x in ...`, `x` *is* the first item of the list `split` returns (on the first iteration, on the second it's the second item, i.e. `"y"`).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you would ever want to do this, but if for some reason you would like to use a `for` loop for this:

```
>>> for x, y in ["x=y".split("=")]:
...   print x
...   print y
... 
x
y
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the split function is returning a list. In the context of a for loop, it gets one item at a time. Eg: `'k=y'.split('=')` returns a list containing `['k', 'y']`. Since it's in the for loop you get 'k', then 'y'.

The reason it works outside of the for loop is because it sees the entire list at once versus one item at a time in the for loop and is able to unpack it.

To fix it, you could split the data into a list of tuples outside the for loop, and loop through that. Eg: `[('x', 'y'), ...]`